# Using Paypal and ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I have 2 websites, one of them just plain HTML and php, the other one asp.net.
The problem is, i want to use the PHP website with the paypal buttons to sell my product.
Then they get redirected (after successfull payment) to the asp.net website, 
where they can create an account.
That page should be able to get all the custom variables from the paypal redirect, but i don't want them to be visible in the URL.

Is this possible?
And if not, any suggestions?

Comment: Are your websites on the same server? Or could they access one database?

Comment: They are on the same server, but only the ASP.net app can reach the DB  

EDIT: Unless i change to MySQL5, because our DB has some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will receive all necessary data from PayPal to URL, specified as return URL. Validate these values and that's all :)

Comment: But the data should not get on the website where the user buys the product, the data should only be known on the other website, how would i do that?

Comment: Yes, you are to access DB, where user has bought products either to implement some kind of service to fetch data from PHP site:
http://www.your-php-eshop.com/products/getinfo/UID-OF-PURCHASE

Comment: Would it also be possible with temporary XML Files in a protected folder?

Comment: I don't like to create any files (especially with some sensitive information). Assign unique ID to each purchase (simple MD5 is ok) with time-to-live, pass it to PayPal and back to return URL.

Comment: No one answered me directly in the way i expected, but i did fix it by using your answer, so thanks :D

Comment: You are welcome :) Really, it is difficult to advise, w/o knowing too much about your system

Answer (score 1):

PayPal has an API for this that is not about passing variables around.

This is the Express Checkout option you are speaking of.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted

You define a callback URL that will provide you with that information.

I have a library to do this for KitGUI.com but its not open source.